# DialogFragment does not show background on versions before Android 5.0

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I recently started with testing before launch, so I can see what my app looks like on other devices. For some reason, the DialogFragment's background does not seem to work on phones with android versions before 5, so on all the tests only Android 5.0+ shows the background, while 4.4 and below is just a default dark dialog.

The background is defined in the layout .xml file like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/phone_like_bc"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

But it does not show background on versions below 4.4... Why is this happening?

My DialogFragment class:

```
public class SettingDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    Context c;
    ComputerClass cl;
    Game game;

    public static SettingDialog newInstance() {
        SettingDialog f = new SettingDialog();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    public void params(Context c, ComputerClass cl, Game game){
        this.c = c;
        this.cl = cl;
        this.game = game;

    }




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle sis){
        super.onCreate(sis);
        //      setContentView(null);

        int style, theme;

        style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME;
        theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog;


        setStyle(style, theme);

    }

    private View v;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings, container, false);
        this.v = v;
        setButtons();
        return v;
    }
    Button bSettBack, bChangeLanguage;
    CheckBox cbSound;

    private void setButtons(){
        bSettBack = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bSettBack);
        bChangeLanguage = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bChangeLanguage);
        cbSound = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cbSound);

        bChangeLanguage.setOnClickListener(this);
        bSettBack.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbSound.setOnClickListener(this);
        updateCBSound();
    }
    private boolean music;
    private void updateCBSound(){
        this.music = cl.music;
        cbSound.setChecked(music);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bSettBack:
                dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.cbSound:
                music = Maths.invertBoolean(music);
                cl.music = music;
                break;
            case R.id.bChangeLanguage:
                cl.save();
                game.showLanguageScreen();
                break;


        }

    }
}
```

I'm only using the default folder. That means there is only one layout file for all versions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would also help if you attach the code of your DialogFragment.

Comment: oh right, sorry. i'm new at this

Comment: Check that your start.xml not overridden in the res/layout-v21 folder.

Comment: start.xml? what is that

Comment: I have no layout v21 folder